# Number of Networks

Tags: networking, subnet

If I will have this Class A Subnet

Class A:

Default Subnet Mask : 255.0.0.0
Host per network : 16,777,214
Number of networks : 128

---

How can I find the number of Networks? (I mean the number 128 above)

---

I can find the host per network by using : 256^(number of zeroes) - 2
example . 255.0.0.0

What I did is : 256^3 = Answer - 2 I used the exponent 3 because the sub-net has 3 zeroes in it.

but what if I will use 255.255.240.0. Can I still use that formula above to get the Host per Network?

Answer (score 0):

First you should understand the main 3 ip address classes.
Class A - 0-127
Class B - 128-191
Class c - 192-223

then you should understand about network bits and host bits of a IP Address.
In class A ip addresses, first 8 bits are the network bits and remaining are host bits.
In class B ip addresses, first 16 bits are the network bits and remaining are host bits.
In class C ip addresses, first 24 bits are the network bits and remaining are host bits.

In class A ip address, first bit should be always remains as 0.
In class B ip address, first two bits which are always 10.
In class C ip address, first three bits set to 110 .

So according to your question, class A has 128 networks. simply take the value of 2^7 .

You can find host per network by : 2^24 -2